# undefined reference to memset shown even though included string.h

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I wrote GDT/IDT table loader for my own kernel, and I linked it with ld. But when I generate the binary, the error has appeared.
`` ld.exe: desc_tablesc.o:desc_tables.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `memcpy' ``

and here's my code:

````
#include "desc_tables.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <stdint.h>


static void init_idt()
{
   __idt_ptr.limit = sizeof(idt_entry) * 256 -1;
   __idt_ptr.base  = (u32int)&idt_entries;

   memset(&idt_entries, 0, sizeof(idt_entry)*256);

   idt_set_gate( 0, (u32int)isr0 , 0x08, 0x8E);
   . . .
   idt_set_gate( 31, (u32int)isr31, 0x08, 0x8E);

   idt_flush((u32int)&__idt_ptr);
}```
````

Comment: did you try to include `#include <string.h>` for memory-related operations? There is where `memset`, and `memcpy` are defined.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: On the top of the `desc_tables.c` file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that a header does not provide any definition of a function. It only provides declarations. (normally). It only allows you to compile without error because the compiler knows that there is a function `memset` somewhere else. You have a linker problem.

Comment: From the code snippet I assume you are using some embedded system. Normally `memset` etc. are automatically linked with your program. It seems that you need to specify the lib manually for your build environment.

Comment: @campescassiano i miscopied the code. there was an include code.

Comment: @Gerhardh should i declare it in the ld command line?

Comment: i'm using standard library in i386 system....

Comment: You need to check with the manual of your compiler/linker toolchain how to provide C standard library to the linker

Comment: Ok i got it thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: It appears that you are writing your own operating system.  You need to provide your own implementations of all standard library functions you use.